# looking for a good documentation/tutorial for sybase

Tags: database, sybase

I need to work with this db and would like to get a quick start. Would anyone recommend a decent documentation/tutorial/examples?

I didn't find anything useful at the official [website](http://www.sybase.com)

Comment: What type of work you plan to do? DB administration? Programming?

Comment: Both actually. mostly programming (c++)but I want to know my way around admin console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the documentation for the iAnywhere products are on [DocCommentXchange](http://dcx.sybase.com/dcx_home.html). They include programming guides with some examples.

You might also be interested in [SQLA](http://sqla.stackexchange.com), the Sybase SQL Anywhere stack overflow clone.

*Note that these sites aren't geared towards ASE or other non-SQL Anywhere products.*

Answer (score 3):

This is the one that I used when I was learning sybase.  Its big, but you can search for individual topics to learn only what you need.

http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/srg1100e/sqlref.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you take a look at the sybase manuals online, choose your database and language then you can see the various reference manuals etc.

http://sybooks.sybase.com/nav/base.do

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sypron.nl/syblinks.html

Rob Verschoor has a lot of interesting information on sybase ASE/RS